# How to change image permission with PHP and chmod?

Tags: php, chmod

As I want to display the uploaded images on website I get the message: "You don't have permission to access /funProject/uploads/328/20.jpg on this server".

I had that problem before and I solved it with using `chmod` but somehow I deleted that solution and I can't make it now.

I got a function like that:

```
function upload_image($image_temp, $image_ext, $album_id) {
  $album_id = (int)$album_id;

 mysql_query("INSERT INTO `images` VALUES ('', '".$_SESSION['user_id']."', '$album_id',  
 UNIX_TIMESTAMP(), '$image_ext')");


$image_id = mysql_insert_id();
$image_file = $image_id.'.'.$image_ext;
move_uploaded_file($image_temp, 'uploads/'.$album_id.'/'.$image_file);

create_thumb('uploads/'.$album_id.'/', $image_file, 'uploads/thumbs/'.$album_id.'/');
}
```

What I have tried something like that (and doesn't work):

```
mysql_query("INSERT INTO `images` VALUES ('', '".$_SESSION['user_id']."', '$album_id', 
UNIX_TIMESTAMP(), '$image_ext')");

chmod($image_file, 0755);
```

How can I change the permission of the uploaded image with using `chmod` in this function?

Comment: echo out `$image_file` before you try to chmod to see if it really is the right thing you are trying to change permissions for. You might have to add in the path again e.g. `uploads/$album_id/$image_file`. You can also add in a file_exists to check if the file is really there. Aiding you in finding out if you really are editing the right thing.

Answer (score 0):

That worked!

```
mysql_query("INSERT INTO `images` VALUES ('', '".$_SESSION['user_id']."', '$album_id',  
UNIX_TIMESTAMP(), '$image_ext')");
chmod("/somedir/uploads", 775);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
chmod('uploads/'.$album_id.'/'.$image_file, 0755);
```

you should set permission on the real location where your file were put ...